# tried running my first flutter app but giving me troubles cant open actually

Tags: flutter

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
```

Initializing gradle...
Finished with error: ProcessException: Process

```
C:\Users\Acer\AndroidStudioProjects\encarta_first_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Unzipping C:\Users\Acer\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv\gradle-4.10.2-all.zip to C:\Users\Acer\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv

Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Command: `C:\Users\Acer\AndroidStudioProjects\encarta_first_app\android\gradlew.bat -v`

Comment: please share flutter doctor comand result for help.

Comment: update your gradle-wrapper.properties as follows distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip

Comment: Run `flutter doctor` in the command prompt and see if there is anything wrong with your Android SDK setup.

Answer (score 0):

its because you dont have gradle-4.10.2 version on your computer.
Solution 1 using Visual Studio Code:
 1. go to folder menu android->gradle->graddle-wrapper.properties
 2. change gradle version to your computer version

Example: i have gradle version 5.4.1 on my laptop

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/**gradle-5.4.1**-all.zip
```